# PixelJunk shooter two-player mode greyed out

Tags: steam, pixeljunk-shooter

I've just installed PixelJunk shooter on my Mac and the Two player option is greyed out.
I've tried it on both Windows and OSX. Is there any way to unlock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by installing the Steam version instead of the DRM-free version from the Humble Store.